# Running k-medoids algorithm in ELKI

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, elki

I am trying to run ELKI to implement k-medoids (for k=3) on a dataset in the form of an arff file (using the ARFFParser in ELKI):

[image]

The dataset is of 7 dimensions, however the clustering results that I obtain show clustering only on the level of one dimension, and does this only for 3 attributes, ignoring the rest. Like this:

[image]

Could anyone help with how can I obtain a clustering visualization for all dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELKI is mostly used with *numerical* data.

**Currently, ELKI does not have a "mixed" data type, unfortunately.**

The ARFF parser will split your data set into **multiple relations**:

1. a 1-dimensional numerical relation containing `age`
2. a LabelList relation storing `sex` and `region`
3. a 1-dimensional numerical relation containing `salary`
4. a LabelList relation storing `married`
5. a 1-dimensional numerical relation storing `children`
6. a LabelList relation storing `car`

Apparently it has messed up the relation labels, though. But other than that, this approach works perfectly well with arff data sets that consist of numerical data + a class label, for example - the use case this parser was written for. It is a well-defined and consistent behaviour, though not what you expected it to do.

**The algorithm then ran on the first relation it could work with, i.e. `age` only.**

So here is what you need to do:

1. Implement an efficient data type for storing mixed type data.
2. Modify the ARFF parser to produce a *single* relation of mixed type data.
3. Implement a *distance function* for this type, because the lack of a mixed type data representation means we do not have a distance to go with it either.
4. Choose this new distance function in k-Medoids.
5. Share the code, so others do not have to do this again. ;-)

Alternatively, you could write a script to encode your data in a numerical data set, then it will work fine. But in my opinion, the results of one-hot-encoding etc. are not very convincing usually.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply Erich! Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now, but if I do it I'll definitely share the code! I did obtain a similarity matrix based on all attributes though, but I am confused which parser to select for that, could you please help with that?

Comment: You should be able to keep the parser as is then (it worked well enough); and just set the distance to the *external* file based distance function in k-medoids.